# Sidebar now showing all folders that contains app

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to configure debugging in the container. As you can see in the picture I have attached to a running container but there is no app directory on the left sidebar, but as you can see manage.py file exists. How can I fix this and see all folders on the left side?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the tab that says "manage.py" and select **Reveal in side bar**.

Comment: it adds only manager.py file, but there are more files , all app folders are missing

Comment: Right-click on the tab that says "manage.py" and select **Reveal in Explorer**. Do you see the files you expected?